# SSML support in AWS Alexa V2

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, ssml

I am working on updating an Alexa skill from V1 to V2. But it appears for some reason SSML is not working in V2 version. These are a few scenarios I tried.

Tied directly passing the ssml,

```
const speechText = 'This <break time=\"0.3s\" /> is not working';

return handlerInput.responseBuilder
      .speak(speechText)
      .reprompt(speechText)
      .getResponse();
```

Also, Tried as an object,

```
 var speechText = {
      type: "SSML",
      ssml: 'This <break time=\"0.3s\" /> is not working',
  };

 return handlerInput.responseBuilder
      .speak(speechText)
      .reprompt(speechText)
      .getResponse();
```

Does anyone have an idea, what I might be doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: shouldn't SSML be wrapped in `<speak>` tags?

Comment: I tried by adding the <speak>, but the documentation says it is not necessary for V2. That is why I removed the <speak> tag.

Comment: could it be the issue with Response Builder not escaping speech for SSML? I see it has been closed 3 days ago: https://github.com/alexa/alexa-skills-kit-sdk-for-nodejs/issues/472 ... Try removing those escape characters

Comment: Yes, You are correct. Updating the library fixed the issue

Comment: - Great I'll add answer below for you to mark correct - this may be helpful to more people!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As we established in the comment section of the original post.

**Response Builder** prior to Release **v.2.5.1** was not escaping invalid SSML characters: `&, <, >, ", '` this issue has been raised with Alexa team [here](https://github.com/alexa/alexa-skills-kit-sdk-for-nodejs/commit/7a4f215dea1b5383f61dae4674d31ba867b5bb53) and is fixed with Release 2.5.1

**Updating the library fixes the problem**

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
const speechText = `This <break time="0.3s" /> is not working`;

return handlerInput.responseBuilder
      .speak(speechText)
      .reprompt(speechText)
      .getResponse();
```

This construction is helpful also when you want to provide a variable into the `speechText`:

```
const lengthInSeconds = 5;
const speechText = `This <break time="${length}s" /> is not working`;
```

Comment: Though interesting as an example this is not solution to the problem as OPs way of constructing a string is correct even though escaping of double-quotes in single-quoted string is not necessary